# Conditional rendering with buttons in React

Tags: reactjs

been working with React for a few weeks and I'm trying to get conditional rendering to work. I'm working with a table with a few rows, where each row has a 'edit' and 'delete' button. On the 'Secured' column, where the values are **false**, I would like to have both buttons to not display. I have tried to render the buttons to be hidden and with some logic, the buttons would display if the props were not false. I'm using the ConfigComponent on another piece of code where I'm displaying all of the table values.

**See table Below:**

```
const ConfigComponent = (props) => {
console.log(props.secured)
if (props.secured !== true) {
    return (
    <tr>
        <td>{props.configCategory}</td>
        <td>{props.configValue}</td>
        <td>{props.description}</td>
        <td>{props.configTypeId}</td>
        <td>{props.dataTypeId}</td>
        <td>{props.secured}</td>
        <td>{props.createdDate}</td>
        <td>{props.modifiedDate}</td>
        <td>{props.modifiedBy}</td>
        <td>{props.id}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" hidden={!props.secured} onClick={() => props.onClick(props.id)}>Edit</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" hidden={!props.secured} onClick={() => props.onDelete(props.id)}>Delete</button></td> 
    </tr>
    )} 
else {
        return (
        <tr>
            <td>{props.configCategory}</td>
            <td>{props.configValue}</td>
            <td>{props.description}</td>
            <td>{props.configTypeId}</td>
            <td>{props.dataTypeId}</td>
            <td>{props.secured}</td>
            <td>{props.createdDate}</td>
            <td>{props.modifiedDate}</td>
            <td>{props.modifiedBy}</td>
            <td>{props.id}</td>
        </tr>
        )}
}


render() {
    let configList = this.state.configList
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold py-3 mb-4">Config List</h3>
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Config Category</th>
                        <th>Config Value</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>ConfigTypeId</th>
                        <th>DataTypeId</th>
                        <th>Secured</th>
                        <th>Created Date</th>
                        <th>Modified Date</th>
                        <th>Modified By</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {configList.map((config, i) => {
                        return (
                            <React.Fragment key={i}>
                                <ConfigComponent
                                    key={config.id}
                                    id={config.id}
                                    configCategory={config.configCategory}
                                    configValue={config.configValue}
                                    description={config.description}
                                    configTypeId={config.configTypeId}
                                    dataTypeId={config.dataTypeId}
                                    secured={(config.secured).toString()}
                                    createdDate={moment(config.createdDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
                                    modifiedDate={moment(config.modifiedDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
                                    modifiedBy={config.modifiedBy}
                                    onClick={this.editClick}
                                    onDelete={this.deleteClick} />
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand what your question is ...

You make a cast to string

```
secured={(config.secured).toString()}
```

but then you check for an explicit 'true'

```
if (props.secured !== true)
```

I assume this will always return false, removing the cast toString() should bring a better behavior

Comment: I was using the cast to string because on the database, that value is stored as a zero or one bit. I converted that bit to a string to display on the page as true or false.

Comment: still '1' is never === true. You should do secured = Boolean(config.secured) to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" hidden={!props.secured} onClick={() => props.onClick(props.id)}>Edit</button></td>
```

This line is called only when props.secured !== true, it is inside if condition. That means everytime hidden will be true and it wont change.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need the else statement, secondly, I don't see react gives button a "hidden" attribute. You should try -

```
const ConfigComponent = (props) => { console.log(props.secured)
    return (
    <tr>
        <td>{props.configCategory}</td>
        <td>{props.configValue}</td>
        <td>{props.description}</td>
        <td>{props.configTypeId}</td>
        <td>{props.dataTypeId}</td>
        <td>{props.secured}</td>
        <td>{props.createdDate}</td>
        <td>{props.modifiedDate}</td>
        <td>{props.modifiedBy}</td>
        <td>{props.id}</td> {props.secured === true ?
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"  onClick={() => props.onClick(props.id)}>Edit</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  onClick={() => props.onDelete(props.id)}>Delete</button></td> : ""}
    </tr> ) }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this answer would help someone  in the future, there is no need to use **ConfigComponent** , please just try:

```
 <tbody>
    {configList.map((config, i) => {
       <tr>
          <td>{config.configCategory}</td>
          <td>{config.configValue}</td>
          <td>{config.description}</td>
          <td>{config.configTypeId}</td>
          <td>{config.dataTypeId}</td>
          <td>{config.secured}</td>
          <td>{config.createdDate}</td>
          <td>{config.modifiedDate}</td>
          <td>{config.modifiedBy}</td>
          <td>{config.id}</td>
          {config.secured &&
          <>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onClick={() => props.onClick(config.id)}>Edit</button></td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onClick={() => props.onDelete(config.id)}>Delete</button></td> 
          </>
          }
      </tr>
    })}
 </tbody>
```